What is the Vyuha doctrine?
AFAIK - it is a Vaishnavite doctrine that says the supreme Vaishnavite deity manifests in "Vyuhas" such as Pradyumna, Aniruddha et al.
These "Vyuhas" don't seem to be prominent in mainstream scripture like the Itihasas and Puranas and don't seem to have great deeds associated with them like the Avataras.
What is the source of the Vyuha doctrine and which Vaishnavite sects accept it?

It's not true that the Itihasas or Puranas don't mention Vyuhas. Mahabharata talks about it in Detail.

Brahma's prayer to Vishnu -


O lord! O Vasudeva! Through your  favours, I have exactly sung all
that is extremely mysterious in your essence. Create the god
Samkarshana out of your own self. O Krishna! Create Pradyumna out of
your own self.Aniruddha is known as the undecaying  Vishnu and create
him out of Pradyumna. It is Aniruddha who created me, Brahma, the
upholder of the  universe.


921 (61), Bhishma Vadha parva, Mahabharata.


Lord Vishnu tells Narada -


There is no creation in the universe, mobile or immobile, that is
eternal. The only single exception is the eternal Purusha Vasudeva.
The immensely powerful Vasudeva is in the atmans of all creatures. The  great-souled one exists in bodies, known as the accumulation of
the earth, the wind, space, water and light as the  fifth. O brahmana!
Though he cannot be seen, he uses his great valour to enter. That is
how birth occurs, through  the efforts of the lord. Without a
combination of the elements, there cannot be a body. O brahmana!
Without the  jivatman, that combination of elements wouldn’t have
moved. That jivatman is also known as the lord Shesha or
Samkarshana. Using his own deeds, the one who arises from this is
known as Sanatkumara. When all creatures are  destroyed, it is into
him that they merge. The mind of all creatures is known as
Pradyumna. It is from him that  the the doer and cause and effect
arise. Everything in the universe, mobile and immobile, is generated
from  Aniruddha. He is also known as Ishana and he manifests himself
through all his deeds. The illustrious Vasudeva is  kshetrajna and
possesses no qualities in his soul. When that illustrious one is born
in any creature, he is known as  the lord Samkarshana. Pradyumna is
said to be generated from the mind and is born from Samkarshana.
Aniruddha  is generated from Pradyumna and is consciousness, or
Maheshvara.


1654 (326), Moksha Dharma Parva, Mahabharata.

